# jQuery Chosen bind events to keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

Here is the structure of my HTML :

```
<select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Choose an color:">
    <option value="1">red</option>
    <option value="2">blue</option>
    <option value="3">green</option>
    <option value="4">black</option>
</select>
```

And here is the javascript portion, in here it shows how easy it is to bind a click event :

```
    $(document).on('click', '.active-result', function () {
        var color = $(this).text()
    })
    // do something with color
```

I have tried binding to key up/down and keypress with success. But :
Here is my use case : 
I need to bind the event to the ENTER key, I have tried binding the event to `e.which == 13` and prevent defaults but with no success. Also I have to mention that this piece of code is applied to a bootstrap Modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would get you the color and change the value of the dropdown on keypress - Enter.

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.chosen-select', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 )
    {  
       var selectedTarget = $(this).find("option:selected");
        alert($(selectedTarget).text());
        $(this).val($(selectedTarget).val());       
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghjhjz03/4/

Comment: I might be mistaken but I don't see anything get alerted when I use arrow down and press enter.

Comment: You will get the alert following an independent `enter` on the kbd. Works for me.

Comment: you are right. I think I prevented the alerting functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Try attaching the keydown event of jQuery:

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.chosen-select', function (event) {
    if ( event.which == 13 ) {      
        event.preventDefault();
        var color = $(this).text();

        // do something with color
    }    
})
```

Comment: adding an `alert(color)` underneath the `// do something .. ` results in no action. that is exactly the problem I am facing. 'Enter' press doesn't register it the selected option as the active result.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with binding the event to the chosen( )   :

```
$(".chosen-select").chosen().keydown ( function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13 )
    {
        var color = $(this).val()
    }
});
```